Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined (lodash
I have an application with react and typescript and I would like to include lodash in my project and I inserted this in the global.d.ts:
import type { LoDashStatic } from "lodash";

declare global {
    let _: LoDashStatic;
}

But when I go to my web page I get this error in console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
Of course I've already added lodash and @types/lodash into my environment
I expect it can use lodash globally since it has been declared

All you're doing is importing and defining types. Where/how do you actually import Lodash's code?

@T.J.Crowder Thanks, you're right! I'm still learning TS and it doesn't interpret my code well. Finally I pass through window._ to define lodash; Is it okay?

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but here in 2024, I wouldn't use a global _ at all. Lodash fully supports JavaScript modules (which you're using above). I'd just import what you need from it in the module(s) where you need it. For instance, if you were using the pick method, you could just do import { pick } from "lodash"; or import pick from "lodash/pick"; (more about the difference here). There's no need for you to do your own declare global.
